# Skipping n elements iteratively while slicing a list in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, slice

I have a big array of 10573 elements and I want to group them into chunks but skipping two elements after each chunk.

I have the code to divide the list into chunks:

```
chunk_size= 109
for i in range(0, len(ints), chunk_size):
    chunk = ints[i:i+chunk_size]
```

But how do I skip or delete two elements from the big list iteratively, i.e., after attaining each chunk of size 109?

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Add 2 to the chunk size when using it in the iteration.

```
chunk_size= 109
for i in range(0, len(ints), chunk_size+2):
    chunk = ints[i:i+chunk_size]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use modular arithmetics :

```
blocksize = chuncksize + 2
newints = [i for i in ints if i%blocksize < chuncksize]
```

The other way is to loop backward:

```
blocksize = chuncksize + 2
for i in range(len(ints), 0, -blocksize)
    ints.pop(i+chuncksize)
    ints.pop(i+chuncksize+1)
```

Note: Did not test.